# GIF as css background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have something like this in css

```
.ajax-loader {
    background-image: url(../images/icon/loader.gif);
}
```

and used on HTML elements like this

```
<div class='ajax-loader'></div>
```

my question is:

If the *ajax-loader* style is used multiple times in a single page, will the image *loader.gif* be loaded multiple times or only once?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: sorry, forgot the question mark. updated XD

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you're asking..

Comment: @Patrick, updated again, hope my explanation is understandable this time XD...........
update to your comment: welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image will be loaded once.This is very simple like `object-oriented programing`.Define a class once and use everywhere.The same thing is followed in css.

Once the image is loaded you can use it everywhere and also this is a good programming approach